# WiX Why not just suppress all ICE errors?

Tags: user-interface, wix

I've been going through a WiX textbook recently (**WiX: A Dev's Guide** by *Nick Ramirez*, a pretty great book), and at the beginning of the UI chapter it shows how to (in Visual Studio) simply suppress all ICE warnings so you can go about your business.

Later, it gets back to the ICE errors, and supposedly shows the student how to deal with them: define the five dialogs `FilesInUse, Error, FatalError, UserExit`, then change it here if *this* and change it there if *that*, yadda-yadda-yadda.

Following the text verbatim launches me further down a regressive rabbit hole, it doesn't fix the ICE errors.

So here's what I do when I get an ICE error: I suppress it!  And, so far, it's been great!

So my question(s) are:

- Why should I *not* simply suppress the ICE errors I get?
- Where to learn how to deal with them legit?  I can't help but think my "suppress" method will come back to bite me eventually.

Answer (score 2):

You should not suppress the errors because they are there for a reason - they point to places\errors that can cause problems.

Because let's face it - probably not many people know how everything works down there and all the hidden connections between properties and how one setting can affect the other. The errors are a way to warn you about these connections and possible pitfalls.

Yes, sometimes they are false alarms but for most cases they will help you to avoid situations where the installer does not behave the way it should and you have no idea why.

Especially since if you suppress a single ICE error you in fact suppress all instances of the error, not just in one place\line (you might suppress dozens of errors in one file and if even one of them caused a problem you might loose yourself in the search\debugging).

I think that you should learn how to deal with them by trial and error and by asking in different places like this or the wix users forum. Just keep in mind - not always there is a single right way to solve an error.

Personally, I chose not to suppress warnings (at all), I prefer to see them and research each one then risk ending up with unexpected behavior.

Comment: I suppress ICE errors when the error explicitly states when it doesn't apply (mutually exclusive components installing to the same location) or I've intentionally violated the ICE with a good reason and know exactly why I am doing it.

Comment: @TeaHunny I agree that not suppressing errors is the best practice.  I don't let warnings pass when I code in other languages, much less an actual error.  However, so far I've just been creating really simple UIs -- the user enters a few pieces of information and hits GO.  I'm just questioning if I need to spend a bunch of time figuring out these ICE errors.  I suppose I will, though, and adopt Brian's outlook:  suppress them if you know why you're suppressing them.

Comment: I partially agree with Brian - in theory that sound great, if you know what you are doing you can supress the unrelevant things.  
The main drawback is that the suppress is global and not per item\line - you (or someone else that is maintaining the code) can add new lines\items that generate the errors (and there was no intention to ignore the errors\they are real errors) - no one will be aware if them.